# Load Balanced Apache keeps browser/user on same server until restart

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, keepalive

So we have a load balancer setup to pass off our http connections to an array of six servers .. I have disabled KeepAlive and for some reason, only after I restart apache, does my additional connections/requests get routed to a different server (random in the pool) .. any tips?

I'm 100% sure our load balancer is doing as it should with 0 persistence as any new connections get passed around without a problem.

Comment: What load balancer are you using?  It's not really possible to answer without knowing that.

Comment: Barracuda 340 with persistence disabled and routing requests evenly within the pool of 5 servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mod_proxy_balancer then read the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) for the module which gives some tips at the end at diagnosing stickyness issues via the log.

Have you tried accessing the site from different clients to see if they get always get forwarded to the same server?

Comment: No mod_proxy_balancer running. Might be worth noting that we have enough modules for minimal operation and that's about it on all of our servers.

Yes, I have tested from multiple servers and networks manually with browsers, a simple telnet to port 80 and using apaches ab tool.